# Is it possible to check, wifi and ethernet seperatly in Java?

Tags: java, wifi, ethernet

I need to test if there is Internet connection. But, the device has Ethernet 2 routers, one for Ethernet and one for 3G connection. This is needed for a diagnostics program. I am using java 1.7, and the op system of the device is Ubuntu 13.10. 
I tried a ping test but I couldn't find a way to differentiate between he two. Is this possible at all? Any suggestions? (for 2 days I've been trying to find an answer on google.)
PS: if someone up or down votes this, than please tell me the reason for it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know pure scientific way to do this but this is what I can recommend.

Take a look on the following article: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html

Run the example. When I did this I got output like this:

```
.....................
Display name: Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter - VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
Name: eth17

Display name: Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
Name: net14
.....................
```

etc, etc.

As you can see the display name of wi-fi adatpers contain this character sequence "Wi-Fi". Try this on your device. If the same happens you can parse the display name of `NetworkInterface` and decide whether this is an wi-fi adapter.

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you. As soon as i'll get it to work, i'll mark your response as an answer. And thank you for your time.